# jQuery 1.8.3 not supporting in IE 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using jQuery 1.8.3 version but it is not executing in IE 6 whereas it is executing fine in IE 7.

This is the code I have written:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" />
```

The date picker does not get rendered properly. When I click on the text box, no calendar is shown.

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working? Any errors in the console? Any unexpected behavior?

Comment: I am supposed to get a Date picker when i run this code but nothing is being displayed when i click on the text box.It is supposed to show calendar but its not showing.

Comment: Please just let IE6 die

Comment: That also counts for IE7, IE8 and IE9.